# How to change the current folder name in Powershell

Tags: powershell, directory, rename

How can I change the current folder name in Powershell? After cutting the basename I want to rename the current basename with $NewName2. But all tries don't work.
Are there any hints for me for the correct Rename-Item syntax.

Example:

current Basename: Ultralongfoldernametochange

after cutting:
$NewName2: Ultralongf

```
$AllDir = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath E:\ -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object { $_.FullName.Length -ge 95 }

foreach($file in $AllDir)
{

 if ($file.Basename.Length -ge 44) 
    {
    $NewName2 = ($file.BaseName[0..9] -join '')
    Rename-Item ???
    }
}
```

Comment: `Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $NewName2 ` should work

Comment: Since you are recursively changing Directory names, the best thing is to do that in reverse order, otherwise you may be trying to rename a subfolder whose parent folder has just been renamed. Append `| Sort-Object {$_.FullName.Length} -Descending` to the `$AllDir = ..` line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define both old name with full path and new name without full path.

You should consider using the `SubString` method rather retrieving an array and joining it : `$file.BaseName.Substring(0, 10)` will retrieve the 10 first characters (0 is the position of the first character, 10 to get 10 characters - and not the 10th position).

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath E:\ -Directory -Recurse| ForEach-Object {
   If ($_.BaseName.Length -ge 44)
   {
       $i = 10
       While ((Test-Path "$($_.PSParentPath.SubString(38))\$($_.BaseName.SubString(0, $i))")
          -and $i -lt $_.BaseName.Length)
       {
           $i++
       }
       Rename-Item $_.FullName $_.BaseName.SubString(0, $i)
   }
}
```

`PSParentPath` property always start with the first 38 characters `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::`, so they are remove (while this is not mandatory here, I used to do this - to storing values somewhere, ...).
The `While` loop is to avoid errors if the new name we want to define already exists, if so we try with one more character, etc... until no name are matching.

`$i -lt $_.BaseName.Length` test is to avoid infinity loops.

If there is no match, only the 10 first characters will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can streamline your command as follows, using a [delay-bind script block](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) with [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item):

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath E:\ -Recurse -Directory | 
  Where-Object { $_.FullName.Length -ge 95 -and $_.BaseName.Length -ge 44 } |
  Sort-Object -Descending { $_.FullName.Length } |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Substring(0, 10) + $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- As [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) notes, it is important to start with the longest paths first, so that directories renamed earlier do not interfere with attempts to rename later ones; the [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) call ensures that.
- There could be name collisions, which the above command doesn't try to handle.
- While it is rare for directories to have *extensions*, the above command preserves them, if present, but note that it therefore adds to the length of the resulting new name.
- `$string.Substring(0, 10)` is the faster equivalent of `$string[0..9] -join ''` (or, more succinctly, `-join $string[0..9]`)

Comment: when you have several folders with same name at start, you will get errors since the rename could use an existent name

Comment: Thanks, @CFou - that's why the answer says "There could be name collisions, which the above command doesn't try to handle."

Comment: @CFou, given the focus of the question - `Rename-Item` syntax - I decided not to tackle the collision part (which the OP's code also doesn't).